# Running Python Command on Cygwin Prompt (Windows 8)

Tags: python, windows, bash, python-2.7, cygwin

I know this question has been asked many times, but I spent the entire day trying to figure out what went wrong and I still have no clue about it. As a DBA I a used to executing DB2 commands on cygwin prompt. I have simply added export DB2CLP=**$$** to my .profile file which does the magic each time I start the cygwin prompt.

I am new to python and wondering if something similar can be done to execute pyton commands on the cygwin prompt? I have installed cygwin and python 2.7.9 on my windows 8 machine and have done setup 
for the PATH varible, but I am still unable to run python commands from cygwin prompt. If I enter the python prompt as below it works fine:

Saurabh@Saurabhska ~
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 25 2014, 14:04:36)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > print 'Saurabh'
> > >       Saurabh

However, I would like to run python commands as below which gives an error:
Saurabh@Saurabhska ~
$ python print 'Saurabh'
python: can't open file 'print': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My PATH variable looks like below:
...:/cygdrive/c/Python27:... (... represents other entries)

Also below is the output of which command from cygwin prompt:
Saurabh@Saurabhska ~
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

The /cygdrive/c/Python27 path contains the below files:
DLLs  Doc  include  Lib  libs  LICENSE.txt  NEWS.txt  **python.exe**  pythonw.exe  README.txt  Scripts  tcl  Tools  w9xpopen.exe

Please help to make it run.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "print 'Saurabh'"
```

You need to add the -c (command) flag and put your command in quotes.